# Word order in correlative constructions: the larger the X, the more

Tags: exam-questions, correlative-constructions

The larger the area of forest is destroyed,...

1. ...the more frequent are natural disasters.
2. ...the more frequently natural disasters occur.

Which of the options is correct and why? If both sentences are correct, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Please edit your question to add what you think yourself. I think it's a good question, but I think since it doesn't reflect your effort it has received a down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your sentence should probably be

> The larger the area of forest destroyed,

meaning as the destruction of a forest grows larger, the "**is**" is not necessary

For the second part, both your examples can be used

> the more frequent are natural disasters.
>   the more frequently natural disasters occur.

I assume you mean *mudslides* and *flooding* as "*natural disasters*".